# Google Identity Platform as SAML Identity Provider

Tags: google-cloud-platform, saml, saml-2.0, google-identity

We are currently using Google Identity Platform in some of our customer applications with username/password provider. Now we have some cases where we have third party apps that need to be authenticated against Google Identity Platform and would like to do that using SAML. We first thought that Google Identity Platform could be used as a SAML identity provider and the third party apps itself would be the SAML service provider, but after trying to set it up we realized that it is probably not possible the way we thought.

There is very few documentation on it from Google side and we only found this guide (https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml) and after reading it multiple times its still not clear for us whether Google Identity Platform can be used as fully functional SAML identity provider which identifies user against the same user database as the user/password provider from Google Identity Platform does or if it can only be used if "connected" to a real SAML identity provider.

Is there anyone who also tried to set up what we'd like to and has some more information about it?

Looking forward to finding out more about Google Identity Platform with SAML.

Best,
Marc

Comment: Reviewing your question, I would suggest you use a different forum that is from Stackexchange: [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @mooonli Did you find a solutions yet?